# Show that ${\cal C}(\rho)={\rm Tr}[U(\rho\otimes|0\rangle\!\langle0|)U^\dagger]$ can be corrected iff $t=0$, where $U=I+(e^{it}-1)|\Psi^-〉〈\Psi^-|$

Tags: error-correction

> Let $ \mathcal{C} $ be the quantum channel defined by $$
>  \mathcal{C}(\rho)=\operatorname{Tr}_{2}\left[U(\rho
>  \otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|) U^{\dagger}\right], $$ where $ U $ is the
> two-qubit unitary gate $$ U=I \otimes I+\left(e^{i
>  t}-1\right)\left|\Psi^{-}\right\rangle\left\langle\Psi^{-}\right|,
>  \quad t \in \mathbb{R} $$ $ \left|\Psi^{-}\right\rangle=(|0\rangle
>  \otimes|1\rangle-|1\rangle \otimes|0\rangle) / \sqrt{2} $, and $
>  \operatorname{Tr}_{2} $ denotes the partial trace on the second qubit.
> Show that $ \mathcal{C} $ can be corrected if and only if $ t=0 $.

I wonder if there are any other ways to do this without expanding all the terms.

Comment: What are the Kraus operators of the channel?